# What does "introspection" mean in the context of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, terminology, autoencoders

I have seen papers in which the authors present a modification to some architecture, and claim that it enables "introspective reasoning capabilities" in the network. An example can be seen in the abstract from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10279.pdf) (or if you want some details, *section D + figure 1*), where the authors claim that expressing the model as a variational auto-encoder to reconstruct optical flow results in introspective reasoning. What does this mean, and why would any architecture have this effect?

**Edit:** In the case of encoder/decoder architectures, then I think that if the decoder's aim is to reconstruct the intial input $x$ of the encoder, then comparing this reconstruction to $x$ gives some information about the accuracy of the encoder's output $y$. Alhtough, this only works if $x$ can be expressed as some function $f(y)$. Is that correct?